# What is the best why to synchronize access to net_device structures?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

I am working with linux kernel version 2.6. 
I would like to synchronize access to a **single** net_device structure. 
While searching for an answer in the kernel code, i came across two synchronization mechanisms relevant to this issue:

1. The *dev_base_lock* lock.
2. the *rtnl_lock()* function.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between the two?
2. Is there any thumb rule for using one of the above?
3. Which one of them should i use for synchronizing access to a single net_device
   structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the chapter "8.15. Locking" in **<< understanding linux network internals >>**

The `dev_base` list and the two hash tables `dev_name_head` and `dev_name_index` are protected by the `dev_base_lock`. That lock, however, is used only to serialize accesses to the list and tables, not to serialize changes to the contents of net_device data structures. net_device content changes are taken care of by the Routing Netlink semaphore (rtnl_sem), which is acquired and released with `rtnl_lock` and `rtnl_unlock`, respectively.[*] This semaphore is used to serialize changes to net_device instances from:

- Runtime events

  For example, when the link state changes (e.g., a network cable is plugged or unplugged), the kernel
  needs to change the device state by modifying dev->flags.
- Configuration changes

  When the user applies a configuration change with commands such as ifconfig and route from the net-tools package, or ip from the IPROUTE2 package, the kernel is notified via ioctl commands and the Netlink socket, respectively. The routines invoked via these interfaces must use locks.

[*] Other routines can also be used to acquire and release the semaphore. See include/linux/rtnetlink.h for more details.